# Setting button text color for Alert Dialog with DayNight Theme

Tags: android, android-styles, android-night-mode

I am trying to set text color of the buttons in the alert dialog.
My App supports Day-Night mode.
My AlertDialog theme extends `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert`
and I have overridden `colorAccent` & `android:colorAccent` property but it didn't work and showing me completely different color.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

[image: Alert Dialog Image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Check your internet connection")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                Toast.makeText(this,"Ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }.setCancelable(false)
            .create().show()
    }
}
```

And in colors we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```